# vertically align column in a table with wrapped text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

In the following table, I want the first column to be top-aligned and the second column to be vertically-aligned.  In contrast, LaTeX is aligning with respect to the baseline of the first line of text.

[image]

I am using the `array` package with column definitions `p` and `m`, which supposedly should align as I want (top and middle aligned, respectively).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5in}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.5in}|}
\hline
  abcde fghijk lmnopq & $\Bigg( x \Bigg)$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your first paragraph, but I suspect you might want to just switch the `p` and the `m`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.5in}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5in}|}
\hline
  abcde fghijk lmnopq & $\Bigg( x \Bigg)$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```